# Django filter_class with empty filter value

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-filter

I have a Django Viewset like :

```
class OrderViewSet(...):

    permission_classes = [
        IsAuthenticated, HasApiPermission, CanAdministerHosts, ]
    queryset = Order.objects.all()

    serializer_class = OrderSerializer
    filter_class = OrderFilter
```

and the OrderFilter class:

```
class OrderFilter(APIv3FilterSet):
    """
    Filter for order.
    """
    // some fields

    class Meta:
        model = UserId
        fields = // some fields
```

This work with some value for filter like `GET .../order/?id=1` 
but if I have no filter value like `GET .../order/` the code return error :

```
AttributeError at .../order/\n'NoneType' object has no attribute 'split'
```

This may be because emty filter string result in None type object.
Provided that I have to use filter_class (not filter_backend or whatever), how can I solve this problem ?

Comment: can you add full traceback?

Comment: And `APIv3FilterSet` code also.